# What is the conditional mass function of $X$ given that $Y = i$?

Tags: conditional-probability

First, let me explain the entire problem.

Choose a number $X$ at random from the set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Now choose a number at random from the subset no larger than $X$, that is, from $\{1,...,X\}$.

(a) Find the joint mass function of $X$ and $Y$.

I was able to do this part of the problem. Without explanation, it is $P_{X|Y}(y|x) = \frac{P(X,Y)}{P_X(x)} = \frac{1}{5j}$ where $1 \leq j \leq i$, $1 \leq i \leq 5$.

This is where I encountered a problem.
(b) Find the conditional mass function of $X$ given that $Y = i$. Do it for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

This is what I have done so far...

$P_{X|Y}(X = j | Y = i) = \frac{P(X = j, Y = i)}{P_Y(y)}$

$P(X = j | Y = i) = \frac{1}{5j}$

$P_Y(y)$...

If $Y =1$, then $X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ 
If $Y =2$, then $X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ 
If $Y =3$, then $X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ 
If $Y =4$, then $X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ 
If $Y =5$, then $X = 5$

My reasoning is that if, say $Y=1$, then $X$ can be any number between $1$ and $5$ according to the values $Y$ and $X$ can assume. But when $Y = 5$, I know for a fact that $X = 5$.

However, the solutions that I have say that $P_Y(y) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^5 \frac{k}{5}$.

According to my work above, my answer is not correct. Where did I go wrong?

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Edit: Full solution to the conditional probability... $P_{X|Y}(X = j | Y = i) = \frac{P(X = j, Y = i)}{P_Y(y)} = \frac{\frac{1}{5j}}{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^5\frac{k}{5}}$

Comment: The "solutions" if quoted correctly, are ridiculous. No dependence on $y$, and a probability that is equal to $3$.

Comment: That's what I found...http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rosario/classes/081/100a-2a/100aHW7Soln.pdf (page 16). Also, I will post the full solution to the conditional probability for part b.

Comment: in that PDF there is part "Call this second number
Y" you missed it